# How to get given date + n months in SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I add a given number of month `n=14` to a given date like `2008-01` (January 2008) to get `2009-03` ?

My goal is to show the date in `YYYY-MM` format instead of `foo_id` (which is the number of months) in the query below:

```
SELECT
  foo_id AS "date",
  amount
FROM my_table
GROUP BY foo_id
ORDER BY foo_id;
```

Currently, I can get given date + n months with in months only:

```
SELECT date_part('month' , DATE '2010-01-01' + INTERVAL '124 month') AS "date";
=> 4
```

Comment: What data type is `foo_id`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's an integer (an id actually).

Comment: So how should that integer be converted to a date?

Comment: `SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' + foo_id * INTERVAL '1 month' AS "date" FROM my_table`

Comment: `id` is a rather strange name for a column storing a number of months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interval could be multiplied:

```
SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' + foo_id * INTERVAL '1 month' AS "date" FROM my_table
-- start date + int * 1 month
```

Comment: How would I set format `yyyy-mm` in this case ?

Comment: I finally got it with `to_char(..., 'yyyy-mm')`, thanks to oterh comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_char()` to format the result with only year and month:

```
select to_char(current_date + interval '14 month', 'yyyy-mm');
```

If the number of months is stored in a column:

```
select to_char(current_date + make_interval(months => foo_id), 'yyyy-mm');
```

So

```
with the_table (foo_id) as (  
  values (14)
)
select to_char(date '2008-01-01' + make_interval(months => foo_id), 'yyyy-mm')
from the_table
```

Returns: `2009-03`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a67e2b1e549659b9b60b73ad6f1a6267)

Comment: I'm getting this error: `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts` on `make_interval`

Comment: Then you are running an outdated Postgres version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a67e2b1e549659b9b60b73ad6f1a6267 or `foo_id` isn't an integer as you said it is

Comment: I'm possibly running an outdated version of PostgreSQL indeed.

Comment: Which means you are running an **unsupported** version of Postgres. `make_interval()` goes back to at least [9.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a67e2b1e549659b9b60b73ad6f1a6267) (which is also no longer supported)

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL **9.6.20**

Comment: Then your column isn't an integer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a67e2b1e549659b9b60b73ad6f1a6267

Answer (score 0):

The current date can also be obtained with `now()`:

```
select now() + interval '1 month' * my_table.number_of_months from my_table where id = 222;
```